# EF - A member of the type, 'X', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Boas,

Eu estou a utilizar EntityFramework para passar o resultado desta query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM [Logística$Sales Invoice Header] AS a INNER JOIN [Logística$Sales Invoice Line] AS b ON a.No_ = b.[Document No_] WHERE 1 = 1 AND b.Type = 2 AND a.[Bill-to Customer No_] = 'IC00029' AND b.No_ = 'XFMR2812B' AND b.[Cross-Reference No_] = '20M39' AND a.[Document Date] >= CONVERT(datetime, '02/01/2018', 103) AND a.[Document Date] <= CONVERT(datetime, '01/02/2018', 103)
```

para uma instância da classe Logística_Sales_Invoice_Header. Esta classe foi criada com recurso ao EntityFramework (Code-first).

No entanto, dá-me o seguinte erro:

`The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'FAMO.BaseItems.Database.urano.famNAV.Logística_Sales_Invoice_Header'. A member of the type, 'Sell_to_Customer_No_', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.`

quando a coluna existe na declaração da classe:

```
namespace FAMO.BaseItems.Database.urano.famNAV
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("Logística$Sales Invoice Header")]
public partial class Logística_Sales_Invoice_Header
{
    [Column(TypeName = "timestamp")]
    [MaxLength(8)]
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string No_ { get; set; }

    [Column("Sell-to Customer No_")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Sell_to_Customer_No_ { get; set; }
```

O que poderá ser?

Comment: Você fez o migration? Parece que é alteração no back-end que não foi feito no banco.

Comment: Eu criei a classe de acordo com a tabela e não alterei nada no back-end

Comment: Retire a linha: `[Column("Sell-to Customer No_")]` e testa. Se resolver, eu faço a resposta.

Comment: Eu posso testar isso, mas isso significa que de cada vez que atualizar o modelo do EF tenho que me lembrar de retirar esta linha e penso que não devia de ser assim. Acho que deveria de funcionar sem usar nenhum "truque"

Comment: O "truque" é somente para testar minha hipotese de resposta. Fique tranquilo, se resolver eu posto o resultado completo.

Comment: Não resolveu e o erro é o mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72543/discussion-between-gabriel-coletta-and-antonio-garcez).